# How to make a function that changes initialized coordinates

Tags: python, function, class, constructor, coordinates

I'm struggling with making a function that changes the value of the coordinates if the parameters appropriate.

That's what I made:

```py
class Move:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y


move = Move(5, 5)


def obstacle(axis, value, plus):
    if plus is True:
        if axis == value:
            axis = axis + 1
            print(f"x = {move.x}, y = {move.y}")
    elif plus is False:
        if axis == value:
            axis = axis - 1
            print(f"x = {move.x}, y = {move.y}")


obstacle(move.x, 5, False)
```

The program should print:
x = 4, y = 5

Comment: when you use `axis = axis + 1` etc you are creating a new object and binding the name axis to it; what you are not doing is changing the attribute of the class instance (move.x).

Answer (score 0):

What the program is currently doing is running obstacle(), going inside the "if plus is false" block and changing the axis value from 5 to 4, and that's it.
To print: x=4, y=5 you can:

- Instead of the axis value change the move.x value
- Or print the axis value instead of move.x

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code rewritten to work as you expect. But note that as @IBeFrogs implies move is global so you may as well just change it directly.

```
class Move:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y


move = Move(5, 5)

def obstacle(inst, value, plus):
    if plus is True:
        if inst.x == value:
            inst.x = inst.x + 1
    elif plus is False:
        if inst.x == value:
            inst.x = inst.x - 1
    print(f"x = {move.x}, y = {move.y}")


obstacle(move, 5, False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Parameters in function only takes the value in variable not the variable.
So when you write like this:

```
axis = axis + 1
```

and

```
axis = axis - 1
```

You just change the parameter value axis.
Replace the two lines with:

```
move.x = move.x + 1
```

and

```
move.x = move.x - 1
```

And the final code is like this:

```
class Move:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

move = Move(5, 5)
def obstacle(axis, value, plus):
    if plus is True:
        if axis == value:
            move.x = move.x + 1
            print(f"x = {move.x}, y = {move.y}")
    elif plus is False:
        if axis == value:
            move.x = move.x - 1
            print(f"x = {move.x}, y = {move.y}")

obstacle(move.x, 5, False)
```